# Making `dj` delete two lines in evil mode

Tags: evil

`dj` in vim deletes the current line as well as the next. It's a bit idiosyncratic (in that it doesn't really make sense as a motion) but I've come to rely on it.

In evil, however, `dj` deletes only the current line. How can I remap it so that it has vim's behaviour?

I've tried a few methods and all don't work:

```
(defun delete-two-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-whole-line)
  (kill-whole-line))
```

- using `key-chord.el`: `(key-chord-define evil-normal-state-map "dj" 'delete-two-lines)`
- trying to remap the `j` motion in evil to jump two lines (`(evil-line-move 2)`). This works but affects every use of `j`.
- `dd` is a linewise shortcut; it's not special-cased, so I can't hook into it (why is evil so elegant...)
- `(define-key evil-mode-normal-map (kbd "dj") 'delete-two-lines)`: `d` isn't a prefix key, and this seems like it would interfere with evil's `d` mapping anyway

I'm at my wit's end. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce this, `dj` deletes two lines here.

Comment: Also can't reproduce.  Can you confirm that `j` is bound to the default `evil-next-line`?

Comment: It's bound to `evil-next-visual-line`. I'm trying to replicate the more commonly-used parts of my vim setup basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should have used `(define-key evil-normal-state-map "j" 'evil-next-visual-line)` to remap it instead of `evil-motion-state-map`. Works now.

Comment: You should accept the other question as it keeps the isual line motion and dj  :)

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem, that `dj` deletes only a single line, is caused by the binding of `evil-next-visual-line` to `j`.  So, it could be solved by making `j` call `evil-next-line` instead only after an operator is input.

This can be achieved by mapping `j` to `evil-next-line` in the operator state map, while we simultaneously bind `evil-next-visual-line` to `j` in the motion state map.

I also had the same problem and the following configurations worked for me:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map   (kbd "<remap> <evil-next-line>")     #'evil-next-visual-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map   (kbd "<remap> <evil-previous-line>") #'evil-previous-visual-line)
(define-key evil-operator-state-map (kbd "<remap> <evil-next-line>")     #'evil-next-line)
(define-key evil-operator-state-map (kbd "<remap> <evil-previous-line>") #'evil-previous-line)
```